# Indexable sticker/s callback

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I am using Firebase AppIndexing for stickers.

My problem is I want to add analytics on each sticker so I can create ranking system.(most used/tapped stickers, unused stickers).

Is it possible to keep track each stickers like onclick(callbacks) on each stickers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Gboard won't return information about usage. They said, about a year ago, that's it was on the roadmap but haven't seen any developments there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Firebase to log your user actions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/log-actions) for the indexes

A Code Lab is available [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/app-indexing/#10)